# opennetcf.net.mail attachment help

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce, opennetcf, smart-device-framework

Thanks for looking at my question.

I am trying to figure out attachments for OpenNetCF.Net.Mail.  Here is the code for my SendMail function:

```
public static void SendMessage(string subject, 
  string messageBody, 
  string fromAddress, 
  string toAddress, 
  string ccAddress)
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

    MailAddress address = new MailAddress(fromAddress);

    // Set the sender's address
    message.From = address;

    // Allow multiple "To" addresses to be separated by a semi-colon
    if (toAddress.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (string addr in toAddress.Split(';'))
        {
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(addr));
        }
    }

    // Allow multiple "Cc" addresses to be separated by a semi-colon
    if (ccAddress.Trim().Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (string addr in ccAddress.Split(';'))
        {
            message.CC.Add(new MailAddress(addr));
        }
    }

    // Set the subject and message body text
    message.Subject = subject;
    message.Body = messageBody;

    // TODO: *** Modify for your SMTP server ***
    // Set the SMTP server to be used to send the message
    client.Host = "smtp.dscarwash.com";
    string domain = "dscarwash.com";
    client.Credentials = new SmtpCredential("mailuser", "dscarwash10", domain);

    // Send the e-mail message 
    try
    {
        client.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        string data = e.ToString();
    }
}
```

It is supposed to be a matter of tweaking it in the following way to allow attachments:

```
Attachment myAttachment = new Attachment();
message.Attachments.Add(myAttachment);
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to get the attachment to add.  The lines above should be it with something else in the middle where I actually tell it what file I would like to attach.  Any help on this matter will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks again!

Comment: Do you mean you want multiple attachments or something of that sort?

Comment: Only a single attachment, a zip file

Comment: What code are you using to attach and what error are you getting? Or is it that the Attachment class doesn't have the API required to add files to it?

Comment: It seems the attachment class does not have everything i need.  I have not been able to find out how to actually indicate the filename and path of what I would like to attach.

Comment: I tried using the PocketOutlook attachment class and casting, but there was no conversion available to make that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.attachment.attachment.aspx), you can specify the filename of the attachment as a parameter. Thus, you can give the fullpath as the string parameter.

Comment: Yes, I was able to do that, but the problem is that I cannot cast the PocketOutlookAttachment as an opennetcf.net.mail attachment, which is what I actually need.

Comment: @jnsohnumr, an old thread on the community forum showed that to be a bug. And looks like they never rectified that bug. See here: http://community.opennetcf.com/forums/t/11325.aspx

Comment: Thanks ended up using a commercial product linked somewhere else:  http://www.enterprisedt.com/products/edtftpnetcompact/purchase.html

Answer (score 0):

They have `AttachmentBase` which can be used to construct a email attachment. However, we cannot add the instance of `AttachmentBase` to the attachments of email message.

I think the `Attachment` class should inherit from `AttachmentBase`. I think this maybe a defect.

Comment: The primary "defect" is that we never implemented attachments.  If you look at the source code, it's just all stubbed out.  I've thought about implementing it - several times in fact - but the reality is that I can still count on one hand the number of requests for it I've gotten and I always have so much more to do.  Maybe for the next version of the CF I'll revisit it.